# inline-flex logo creates weird unwanted padding (CodePen inside)

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I am working on a header which contains a SVG logo and a h1 headline.

Using flex makes the clickable area too long. Using inline-flex makes the clickable area just as long as both items' width is.

When using inline-flex, the SVG logo gets a small padding at the bottom. Try changing inline-flex to flex!

Any ideas how to remove that small padding?

http://codepen.io/dash/pen/vEqGNb

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="header-inner">
        <a href="https://example.org/" class="brand-anchor">
            <svg class="logo" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
                <rect width="120" height="120" style="fill: orange;" />
            </svg> 
            <h1 class="brand">Brand</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: gray;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
}

.brand-anchor {
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
}

a.brand-anchor:link, a.brand-anchor:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 40px;
}

.brand {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same problem as with `display: inline`.
This annoying gap can be avoided by adding `font-size: 0` on the parent:

```
.header-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  font-size: 0;
}
```